# how to get text from website in rss feeds in a view based application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rss, feed

Hi am new to iphone programming,am developing an app which is a quiz app in a view based application.I need to get the questions from the particular site(URL)in the from of the rss feeds in the quiz when start the quiz.so any help will be useful to me.Suggestions will be accepted.

Comment: More information, please. What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried to add the xml file in the project but it is a view based application,generally rss feeds will be done in a navigation based app.i dn't have an idea how to work with rss feeds in a view based application

Answer (score 0):

Send an `NSURLConnection` request to the site and parse it using `NSXMLParser`. 
Here are some links:
[NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thank you for ur rply rohan kapur can you send ur mail id so that i need to talk personally.